# numberVarible Not Displaying to the Right of id: in JavaScript / jQuery Code

Tags: javascript, python, jquery

There are two parts to this question:

**Part A:**

When I run the code below, "numberVariable" is displaying as the text "numberVariable" within the javascript instead of the actual value of 1. How do I get it to display as 1 to the right of id: -- Do I have to pass it in somehow?

Also, alert(numberVariable); does print the value of 1 when I run the HTML.

There's something I'm not understanding with the code as this is the first time I've tried to build a widget.

The code works when I hard code a value of id: "1" into the code, but not when it is id: numberVariable.

**Part B:**

How would I then send numberVariable into the Python file without affecting the callback that already works?

```
"https://example.com/cgi-bin/data.py?callback=?";
```

Thanks for the help.

**Here is the HTML Code:**

```
<script 
src="https://example.com/widget/externalJSfileContainingTheCodeBelow.js" 
async></script><div id="widget" dataVar="1"></div>
```

**Here is the Javascript / jQuery Code**

```
(function () {
  var jQuery;
  if (window.jQuery === undefined) {
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src",
      "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js");
    if (script_tag.readyState) {
      script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
          scriptLoadHandler();
        }
      };
    } else {
      script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
    }
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] ||
      document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
  } else {
    jQuery = window.jQuery;
    main();
  }

  function scriptLoadHandler() {
    jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
    main();
  }

  function main() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

      var element = document.getElementById('widget');
      var numberVariable = element.getAttribute('dataVar');
      alert(numberVariable);

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://example.com/widget/widget-updater.php",
        data: { id: numberVariable }
      });
      var css_link = $("<link>", {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        type: "text/css",
        href: "https://example.com/widget/widget.css"
      });
      css_link.appendTo('head');
      var jsonp_url = "https://example.com/cgi-bin/data.py?callback=?";
      $.getJSON(jsonp_url, function (data) {
        $('#widget').html(data.html);
      });
    });
  }
})();
```

Comment: `dataVar` is an invalid attribute in HTML. Make it `data-var` and get its value with `var numberVariable = element.dataset.var` instead of `var numberVariable = element.getAttribute('dataVar');`

Comment: Also (FYI), `$('#widget').html(data.html);` should be `$('#widget').html(data.html());` otherwise you will be assigning `undefined` to `widget.html()`.

Comment: It's getting the variable as alert(numberVariable); displays 1 in a pop up box. The issue is that this: data: { id: numberVariable } isn't displaying id: 1 when the javascript is run.

Comment: Ignore the dataVar (that's not the significant part here), and put in any variable you want, it does work when I hardcode id: "1" in. also the JSONP callback retrieval from python script on the server works fine.

Comment: Change the alert to the following and work with your Console open and tell me what the output is: `console.log(typeof numberVariable, numberVariable);`

Comment: You haven't specified any complete callback for your AJAX function call and so all the code that follows it will run before the AJAX call returns and therefore `data` won't have a value. Read [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) on how to configure the $.ajax() method.

Comment: "string 1" is the output for the line console.log(typeof numberVariable, numberVariable); in the console

Comment: Ok, that must be the problem.

Comment: And take note of my earlier comment about `widget.html()` being incorrect.

Comment: When widget.html is widget.html() -- error - > Uncaught TypeError: data.html is not a function

Comment: It should be: `$('#widget').html($(data).html());`